# How to call local html file using actionscript in Android AIR app

Tags: android, air, flash-builder

I have made a AIR apk using action-script in Flash builder and the same i wanted to run in android which is running perfectly. but I am not able to open local html file that i have put in sdcard. so i want to open an local HTML file using an AIR app. Please suggest!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by "running" an html ? As I understand this is on Android OS so there is not wrapper needed for flash embedding, therefore any ExternalInterface calls are not valid.

Comment: i have edited and made it more clearer. please check

Comment: Sorry it is still not clear for me. are you trying just to display a HTML content from a local html file, inside your AIR app? Check this http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=UUVx832dLZY for mobile use StageWebView.

Comment: yes i am trying to display an HTML content from a local HTML file

Comment: then check the video i posted above, or this one http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS901d38e593cd1bac3ef1d28412ac57b094b-8000.html

Comment: Hi the issue is solved now.. Thanks to all for your guidelines. I have done connectivity through socket communication.